How can I stop iTerm2 from hiding first line of my clear; ls -F alias command?
I've been using a cls alias over 20 years:
cls="clear; ls -F"

Simply, clears screen, then lists files.  It's become a habit now - I cannot stop using it ...
However, with the newer releases of iTerm2, (version 3.5.4), this alias is hiding the first line of the directory's files.  See Image below.  Is there a setting I can use the change this behavior?


If you run the commands manually, does the same happen? Did you check the release notes of iTerm for relevant changes since the previous release you had installed.

yes, if I run command manually same thing.  also, comparing notes ... friend (who is bash, not fish user like me) also see same results with iTerm2.  And only when clear; ls (listing files) is involved.

It took some effort to search for the appropriate setting for this:
Settings -> Profiles-Terminal (scroll to the bottom)
Uncheck: Show offscreen command at top of session
